# How to create a SQLite3 DB in Android Via JNI (C ? C++)

Tags: android, c++, c, sqlite, java-native-interface

I have been trying to create a new **SQLite3 db (SQLite - C/C++)** in Android via **JNI** but the db file doesn't get created.

*[Tutorialspoint : Connect To Database](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm)*

```
void createDb() {
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open("/storage/emulated/0/Download/sqlite_lite.db", &db);

    if (rc) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "MyApp", "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    } else {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "MyApp", "Opened database successfully\n");
    }
}
```

I get an erro : `Could not create db`

I have the **Permissions** enabled **(manifest)** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What am I missing? I have the above wired up via **JNI** :

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_initDb(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    createDb();
}

public class SQLiteDB {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("sqlite-db");
    }

    public native void initDb();

}
```

How can I get my app to create the **database** file?

Thank you all in advance.

---

### **UPDATE :**

I'm working from **React Native**. This is how I'm getting my **Runtime Permissions** :

```
const requestCameraPermission = () => {
  try {
    PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    ]).then(result => {
      if (
        result['android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION'] &&
        result['android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'] &&
        result['android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'] === 'granted'
      ) {
        console.log('SUCCESS! Permissions Granted!');
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};
```

However, there doesn't seem to be `READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE` available in **React Native**.

Comment: "I have the Permissions enabled (manifest)" -- there is no `READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` require some Java/Kotlin code to request them at runtime; it is unclear if you are doing that. And, that hardcoded path may not exist for your app's process. Pass in the location to store as a parameter to your `initDb()` function, and then start off with some place that you know you can read and write, such as `getFilesDir()` on `Context`.

Comment: Which Android Version? Starting from Android 11 you cannot write outside App's data folder: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare. Thank you for the reply. I am asking for runtime permissions. I've posted an update on how I'm doing this. Would you mind advising. Thank you.